# JavaScript -- Function Basics

Tags: javascript

In the following `get` function: If `parent && parent.parentNode` is true and the return value is `parent.parentNode.selectedIndex` -- will the function return `null` at the end, too?

```
get: function( elem ) {
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    if ( parent && parent.parentNode ) {
        parent.parentNode.selectedIndex;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes...It will...All the time....

Comment: It will always return null, you're not telling it do anything else

Comment: You are not returning anything except `null`. You need `return parent.parentNode.selectedIndex;` inside the function. And then it will return `null` only if your condition fails.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a return statement within the if statement. Return statements in JavaScript return control back to the parent function immediately. So if function 1 calls function 2, as soon as function 2 comes to a return statement, it stops what it's doing and passes control, and data if specified, back to function 1.

```
get: function( elem ) {
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    if ( parent && parent.parentNode ) {
        return parent.parentNode.selectedIndex;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return only a value

> If parent && parent.parentNode is true

or return null

> If parent && parent.parentNode is false

then write the below code

```
get: function( elem ) {
    var parent = elem.parentNode;
    if ( parent && parent.parentNode ) {
        return parent.parentNode.selectedIndex;
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```